# Android studio not displaying some sources

Tags: android, android-source

I downloaded Android's API level 27 sources and i'm interested in debugging some of  the code. But for some reason, not all symbols are resolved (they appear in red). The imports exist and the class source files appear in Android/Sdk/sources. Also, the weird part is that when I debug and attempt to step into a method of an unresolved class symbol, it actually does enter the source code.

Comment: @InsaneCat might I ask why you removed the android-studio tag?

Comment: Because it's not android studio fault you need to just mentioned android tag.

Comment: @InsaneCat But seeing as how I do have the sources, can't it be connected to Android Studio? Or alternatively, maybe there's a way in Android Studio to explicitly point to a source file for a certain class.

Answer (score 0):

```
You've already gone down the list of most things that would be helpful, but you could try:

Exit Android Studio
Back up your project
Delete all the .iml files and the .idea folder
Relaunch Android Studio and reimport your project
By the way, the error messages you see in the Project Structure dialog are bogus for the most part.
```